# Salary calculation in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I am using following Sql statement to calculate salary

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME, @currentDate DATETIME, @currentDay INT, @PerDaycount INT, @Monthcount INT

 DECLARE @currentMonth INT, @lastDayOfStartMonth INT 
 CREATE TABLE #VacationDays ([Month] VARCHAR(10), [DaysSpent] INT,[MonthDays] VARCHAR(10),[PerdayAmt] decimal(8,2),[TotalAmt] decimal(8,2))

 DECLARE @Salary decimal(8,0)


 SET @Salary  = 8000

 SET @startDate = '01/01/2015'
 SET @endDate = '12/07/2015'
 SET @currentMonth = DATEPART(mm, @startDate)
 SET @currentDay = DATEPART(dd, @startDate)
 SET @currentDate = @startDate

 WHILE @currentMonth < DATEPART(mm, @endDate)
 BEGIN
    SELECT @lastDayOfStartMonth =
        DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@currentDate)+1,0)))
    PRINT @lastDayOfStartMonth
    INSERT INTO #VacationDays
    SELECT DATENAME(month, @currentDate) AS [Month],
        @lastDayOfStartMonth - @currentDay + 1 AS [DaysSpent],@lastDayOfStartMonth as a,@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth As dayammt,(@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth ) * @lastDayOfStartMonth - @currentDay + 1 AS totamt

    SET @currentDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @currentDate)
    SET @currentMonth = @currentMonth + 1
    SET @currentDay = 1
 END

 IF DATEPART(mm, @startDate) = DATEPART(mm, @endDate)
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #VacationDays
    SELECT DATENAME(month, @endDate) AS [Month],
        DATEPART(dd, @endDate) - DATEPART(dd, @startDate) + 1 AS [DaysSpent],@lastDayOfStartMonth as a,@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth As dayammt,(@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth ) * DATEPART(dd, @endDate) - DATEPART(dd, @startDate) + 1 AS totamt
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #VacationDays
    SELECT DATENAME(month, @endDate) AS [Month],
        DATEPART(dd, @endDate) AS [DaysSpent],@lastDayOfStartMonth as a,@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth As dayammt,(@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth ) * DATEPART(dd, @endDate) AS totamt
 END

 SELECT * FROM #VacationDays
 DROP TABLE #VacationDays
```

here is the Result :

```
January     31  31  258.06  8000.00
February    28  28  285.71  8000.00
March       31  31  258.06  8000.00
April       30  30  266.67  8000.00
May         31  31  258.06  8000.00
June        30  30  266.67  8000.00
July        31  31  258.06  8000.00
August      31  31  258.06  8000.00
September   30  30  266.67  8000.00
October     31  31  258.06  8000.00
November    30  30  266.67  8000.00
December    7   30  266.67  1866.67
```

the problem is some times monthdays comming wrong as in example dec. has 31 days but getting 30 days.

How to solve this.

Start date and end date can be change as per requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use this query.

```
    DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME, @currentDate DATETIME, @currentDay INT, @PerDaycount INT, @Monthcount INT

   DECLARE @currentMonth INT, @lastDayOfStartMonth INT 
  CREATE TABLE #VacationDays ([Month] VARCHAR(10), [DaysSpent] INT,[MonthDays] VARCHAR(10),[PerdayAmt] decimal(8,2),[TotalAmt] decimal(8,2))

 DECLARE @Salary decimal(8,0)


 SET @Salary  = 8000

 SET @startDate = '01/01/2015'
  SET @endDate = '12/07/2015'
  SET @currentMonth = DATEPART(mm, @startDate)
 SET @currentDay = DATEPART(dd, @startDate)
 SET @currentDate = @startDate

 WHILE @currentMonth <= DATEPART(mm, @endDate)
BEGIN
  SELECT @lastDayOfStartMonth =
  DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@currentDate)+1,0)))
PRINT @lastDayOfStartMonth
IF(@currentMonth != DATEPART(mm, @endDate))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #VacationDays
SELECT DATENAME(month, @currentDate) AS [Month],
    @lastDayOfStartMonth - @currentDay + 1 AS [DaysSpent],@lastDayOfStartMonth as a,@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth As dayammt,(@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth ) * @lastDayOfStartMonth - @currentDay + 1 AS totamt
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #VacationDays
   SELECT DATENAME(month, @endDate) AS [Month],
   DATEPART(dd, @endDate) AS [DaysSpent],@lastDayOfStartMonth as a,@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth As dayammt,(@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth ) * DATEPART(dd, @endDate) AS totamt
END
SET @currentDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @currentDate)
SET @currentMonth = @currentMonth + 1
SET @currentDay = 1
END

SELECT * FROM #VacationDays
DROP TABLE #VacationDays
```

its a bit modified.

Here the changes as per comments below

Changed the condition of While

```
WHILE @currentMonth <= DATEPART(mm, @endDate)
```

Because `@lastDayOfStartMonth` is been calculated inside the while loop . And for December month its not changing and its picking the data of November month which is 30. So i changed it accordingly to get the proper data inside the while loop itself.

Comment: Can you please also *explain* what you did / changed? *It's a bit modified* really isn't very helpful - you need to tell **WHAT** was modified - and why

Comment: i changed the condition of While  `WHILE @currentMonth <= DATEPART(mm, @endDate)`  because @lastDayOfStartMonth is been calculated inside the while loop . And for December month its not changing and its picking the data of November month which is 30. So i changed it accordingly to get the proper data inside the while loop itself. - please check

Comment: @marc_s does the solution and explanation worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Please re-calculate month day after while loop execution, because your while loop not include last month, Add this line after while loop

```
  SELECT @lastDayOfStartMonth =
    DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@currentDate)+1,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME, @currentDate DATETIME, @currentDay INT, @PerDaycount INT, @Monthcount INT

DECLARE @currentMonth INT, @lastDayOfStartMonth INT 
CREATE TABLE #VacationDays ([Month] VARCHAR(10), [DaysSpent] INT,[MonthDays] VARCHAR(10),[PerdayAmt] decimal(8,2),[TotalAmt] decimal(8,2))

DECLARE @Salary decimal(8,0)


SET @Salary  = 8000

SET @startDate = '01/01/2015'
SET @endDate = '12/07/2015'
SET @currentMonth = DATEPART(mm, @startDate)
SET @currentDay = DATEPART(dd, @startDate)
SET @currentDate = @startDate

WHILE @currentMonth <= DATEPART(mm, @endDate)
BEGIN
SELECT @lastDayOfStartMonth =
    DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@currentDate)+1,0)))
PRINT @lastDayOfStartMonth
INSERT INTO #VacationDays
SELECT DATENAME(month, @currentDate) AS [Month],
    @lastDayOfStartMonth - @currentDay + 1 AS [DaysSpent],@lastDayOfStartMonth as a,@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth As dayammt,(@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth ) * @lastDayOfStartMonth - @currentDay + 1 AS totamt

SET @currentDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @currentDate)
SET @currentMonth = @currentMonth + 1
SET @currentDay = 1
END

  IF DATEPART(mm, @startDate) = DATEPART(mm, @endDate)
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #VacationDays
   SELECT DATENAME(month, @endDate) AS [Month],
    DATEPART(dd, @endDate) - DATEPART(dd, @startDate) + 1 AS [DaysSpent],@lastDayOfStartMonth as a,@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth As dayammt,(@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth ) * DATEPART(dd, @endDate) - DATEPART(dd, @startDate) + 1 AS totamt
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #VacationDays
   SELECT DATENAME(month, @endDate) AS [Month],
    DATEPART(dd, @endDate) AS [DaysSpent],@lastDayOfStartMonth as a,@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth As dayammt,(@Salary/@lastDayOfStartMonth ) * DATEPART(dd, @endDate) AS totamt
 END
  SELECT * FROM #VacationDays
  DROP TABLE #VacationDays
```

Try This Code ... And Check Output and Don't select the Last line from output whatever return from this query.

Comment: Can you please also *explain* what you did / changed? Don't just dump your code - tell us what you're doing to achieve the result!

Comment: WHILE @currentMonth **<=** DATEPART(mm, @endDate)